# Create a string in golang with characters that require escaping

Tags: string, go, escaping

I am trying to make a string variable containing :

"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" C:\Users\User\Desktop\Guess.py

Unfortunately I am not succeeding in doing so. Is there a way to put the text about as is into a variable, double quotes and all?

Comment: You can escape quote characters or use backticks `\`` for string literals

Comment: Please can you show me an example since I am new to golang? I understand the backticks. An example for escape quote characters would be appreciated!

Comment: Escaping quote char not working... https://play.golang.org/p/b_MwzoR2gR5

Comment: Here is the correctly escaped version https://play.golang.org/p/CMS78oWTyet

Comment: Thanks Oswin! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 7):

In your example string you have characters that need escaping: `"` and `\`

```
fmt.Println("\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Guess.py")
```

You can also use back quotes to create what is called a raw string which doesn't require escaping those characters.

```
fmt.Println(`"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" C:\Users\User\Desktop\Guess.py`)
```

List of escapes:

> ```
> \a   U+0007 alert or bell
> \b   U+0008 backspace
> \f   U+000C form feed
> \n   U+000A line feed or newline
> \r   U+000D carriage return
> \t   U+0009 horizontal tab
> \v   U+000b vertical tab
> \\   U+005c backslash
> \'   U+0027 single quote  (valid escape only within rune literals)
> \"   U+0022 double quote  (valid escape only within string literals)
> ```

See the [official docs.](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals)